# Как сервером nginx передать программе на C данные, полученный ответ отправить клиенту

Tags: c, nginx

Nginx получает Post-запрос с данными JSON.

1. Необходимо запустить программу C, передать ей в качестве аргумента строку JSON.
2. Дождаться ответа, передать ответ в браузер.
   3 Закрыть запущенный процесс.

Код не нужен, хотелось бы общее направление, куда копать? CGI? Node.js и child_process?

Comment: Минусовщики, может словечко выдавите из себя?

Comment: Nginx не умеет CGI. Так что вам нужен например fcgiwrap (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/). И задача сводится к настройке fcgiwrap и передаче запроса в него из nginx с помощью `fastcgi_pass`

Comment: Я так понял, инструкции fcgiwrap на perl писать надо? Ничего не знаю о perl. Ладно, буду копать CGI - FastCGI.

Comment: Ну если проще, то можно форкать на nodejs. Основная идея, что nginx принципиально не умеет CGI и форки нужно делать где-то в другом месте. На перле или ноде или чём-то ещё это дело вкуса.

Comment: Спасибо. Node мне ближе гораздо. Вопрос: программа C может выполняться до 10 мин. Мне надо WebSocket открывать? Timeout в Nginx увеличивать для этого адреса? Браузер дождётся ответа если http?

Comment: Надо проверять. Обычно при таких долгих обработках уже делают асинхронные очереди. Но в теории можно и таймауты подкрутить.

Comment: Вроде каждый запрос в Nginx выполняется ассинхоронно? А в Node ясно, что промисы или async, или все сложнее?

Comment: Асинхронно в том смысле, что запрос пользователя сразу получает в ответ ID операции, а потом сам ходит раз в N секунд/минут и спрашивает «а дай результат операции ID» и сервер ему отвечает либо «погоди, ещё не готово» либо «вот результат».

Comment: Да, я хотел через вебсокет это делать, в любом случае пользователя надо информировать о ходе процесса. Сообщения должна посылать программа С. Вот только не совсем пойму как дескриптор файла получит прога С, то есть получателя сообщений.